# Print and read from xterm in a multithreaded C program using cat, tee and fifos

Tags: c, multithreading, cat, fifo, tee

I am trying to create a chat interface in my C program.
The program use two fifos to communicate with a forked `xterm` running the commands `cat fifo_out` and `tee fifo_in > /dev/null` at the same time. 
Then a thread is opened for reading input in the *fifo_in
 coming from the terminal thanks to `tee`, in the same time another thread prints message in *fifo_out* and things get displayed in xterm.

All seems to work pretty well... Except when a message has been printed while writing some text in the terminal, splitting the entered text in two parts. This cause a segfault!

Do you have any idea why it happens like that ?

Here is a minimal example:

```
int open_terminal(pid_t *pid, int *pipe)
{
  mkfifo("fifo_in", 0600);
  mkfifo("fifo_out", 0600); 
  pid_t p = fork();
  int fd_in, fd_out;
  switch (p) {
    case -1:
      return -1;
    case 0:
        execlp("xterm", "xterm", "-e", "cat fifo_out & tee fifo_in > /dev/null", NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    default:
        if ((fd_in = open("fifo_in", O_RDONLY)) == - 1)
          return -1;
        if ((fd_out = open("fifo_out", O_WRONLY)) == - 1)
          return -1;
        *pid = p;
        pipe[0] = fd_in; pipe[1] = fd_out;
        return 0;
  }
  return -1;
}


void *message_thread(void *args)
{
  int *fd_out = (int *)args;
  while (1) {
    dprintf(*fd_out, "You're awesome!\n");
    sleep(5);
  }
}


void *input_thread(void *args)
{
  int *fd_in = (int *)args;
  FILE *f = fdopen(*fd_in, "r");
  while (1) {
    size_t n;
    char *line;
    getline(&line, &n, f);
    printf("Read: %s", line);
    free(line);
    if(strcmp(line, "exit\n") == 0)
      return NULL;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pid_t pid;
  int pipe[2];
  if (open_terminal(&pid, pipe) == -1) {
    printf("Can't open terminal.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  pthread_t mt, it;
  pthread_create(&mt, NULL, message_thread, &pipe[1]);
  pthread_create(&it, NULL, input_thread, &pipe[0]);

  pthread_join(it, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

To reproduce my conditions, run the program input some text, wait until some text is printed after your text then type again and enter.

Comment: You may also want to look at the `unlink` command to clean up the fifos when exiting the program. If it makes any difference, you may also want to trim the trailing `'\n'` from the input from `getline`. Since `getline` returns the number of characters read (including the `'\n'`), you can simply use the return (e.g. `nchr = getline (...` and then `line[--nchr] = 0;` to removed the `'\n'`. You then don't need strange looking tests like `strcmp(line, "exit\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `input_thread` function:

```
free(line);
if(strcmp(line, "exit\n") == 0)
```

First you free the memory allocated and pointed to by `line`, then you immediately use that memory. This leads to *undefined behavior*.

And that's not all, because you pass an uninitialized pointer and size to the `getline` function, it will not actually allocate memory since uninitialized local variables have an *indeterminate* value (it will be seemingly random and not very likely zero or `NULL`). Explicitly initialize the variables to zero and `NULL`, and the `getline` function will allocate the memory needed. Using uninitialized local (non-static) variables for anything else but initialization also leads to undefined behavior.

It's probably the undefined behavior from `getline` writing to some seemingly random memory that causes the crash.

Comment: Oops, the `free` isn't in the right place, I didn't see that, but that's not the case in the real program. The real reason was the other, the uninitialized `size_t`. Thank you.